# Android storing GPS Lat and Longs

Tags: android, gps

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    db = new DbAdapter(getBaseContext());
    db.open();

    android_id = Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Waiting for location..." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

  LocationListener onLocationChange=new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            //sets and displays the lat/long when a location is provided
            String latlong = "Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Long: " + loc.getLongitude();  
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), latlong, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 db.insertGPSCoordinates(android_id, Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()), Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));
        } 

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // required for interface, not used
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // required for interface, not used
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
        Bundle extras) {
        // required for interface, not used
        }
    };
    //pauses listener while app is inactive
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locmgr.removeUpdates(onLocationChange);
    }

    //reactivates listener when app is resumed
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,10000.0f,onLocationChange);
    }
```

This code is working for me but it gets Lats and Longs only once. I would like to know how "LocationListener" works ? I fired up the app and took a walk, it only stored 1 set. What am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)
```

Your application only will update location change when your difference of position be of 10000m, 10km. Try with:

```
locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,onLocationChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the GPS thing in a timer thread to force it to update. Different devices behave differently with the GPS listener.

Also make sure your insertDBCoordinates isn't simply doing an update to the same row every time

Comment: don't need to use a timer, location update listener will execute all times that GPS update position

Comment: I didn't realize that your distance was so far in the original post

Comment: you can set the distance you want, i think @user553844 was wrong with that distance